# Where does energy in a photo-emissive cell come from?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

According to most textbooks, photo-electrons are attracted to a positively charged electrode (by connecting it to the positive terminal of a battery). If this is the case, then what is the practical utility of such a cell? The energy driving the photocurrent comes from the external battery, with the solar energy only providing energy to dislodge electrons from the metal surface.

Comment: are you asking about this ?https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/explain-the-working-of-photo-emissive-cell-write-any-two-applications-of-photoelectric-cells/

Comment: Yes, any device that works on the photoelectric effect.

Answer (score 0):

The practical utility would be the detection or measurement of the intensity of light. To give you an example, we had a project in our First-Year undergrad class where we were asked to make a controller that would control the switching of street lights depending on how dark the streets were. We used a photocell to measure the intensity of sunlight and then programmed an Arduino to switch the street lights on and off.

Comment: Ok, so what happens to the kinetic energy of photo-electrons? Can we exploit it somehow, without using an external voltage source?

Comment: @terahertz We have solar cells which operate on the photovoltaic effect for solar energy harvesting. I am not familiar with any device which harvests the kinetic energy of photoelectrons. Even if it's possible to exploit it, the kinetic energy should be too small for any practical purpose. But I'm not a physicist nor an electrical engineer, so take my words with a grain of salt.

Comment: @terahertz it is the way one gets energy from solar panels! see 2.3 and 2.4 here http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.j.ep.20221201.01.html#Sec2.3

Comment: That is precisely my question. If we can get energy from the photovoltaic effect, can we get energy from the photo-electric effect?

Comment: @Mechanic The kinetic energy of electrons is the energy they get from the incident optical wave. In a photovoltaic cell, it is this energy that is converted to electrical energy. It is by no means insignificant.

Comment: @terahertz As far as I know, there is no photoelectric emission of electrons in a photovoltaic cell. The incident light produces a potential gradient across the junction and it's that potential difference that drives the current.

Comment: @Mechanic Yes, there is no emission of electrons in a photovoltaiccell. But my question is, what happens to the incident light energy in a photo-electric situation.

Comment: @terahertz The incident light energy is proportional to the frequency of the light, and if the frequency exceeds the threshold frequency for the particular material, it will cause photoelectric emission. The excess energy would manifest as the kinetic energy of the emitted photoelectron. The number of photons emitted would then be proportional to the intensity of the incident light beam.